# Brainfuck compressor in Python

Tags: python, compression, brainfuck

Just for fun, I created a script called TinyBF which can compress [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) programs into a format half their size. For example, take a famous [hello world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68494/) program clocking in at 78 bytes:

```
--<-<<+[+[<+>--->->->-<<<]>]<<--.<++++++.<<-..<<.<+.>>.>>.<<<.+++.>>.>>-.<<<+.
```

When put into TinyBF format, it is only 39 bytes:

```
7#!00"7!'!7?,,,?#B!?.>!$,.>?!.
```

The steps for encoding are:

1. Translate all characters in the input using the following dictionary: `{'>': '2', '<': '3', '+': '4', '-': '5', '.': '6', ',': '7', '[': '8', ']': '9'}`.
2. Split the string into chunks of two characters each - pad the last item with a trailing zero if it is only one digit long.
3. Make a string using the resultant charcodes of the previous list.

Without further ado, here's the compress and decompress methods (`tinybf.py`):

```
def compress(code):
    """compress(code): Compress a string of Brainfuck code into TinyBF format."""
    translated = code.translate({62: 50, 60: 51, 43: 52, 45: 53, 46: 54, 44: 55, 91: 56, 93: 57})
    return "".join(chr(int(translated[pos:pos + 2].ljust(2, "0"))) for pos in range(0, len(translated), 2))

def decompress(code):
    """decompress(code): Decompress a string of TinyBF code into Brainfuck format."""
    translated = "".join(str(ord(c)) for c in code).translate({50: 62, 51: 60, 52: 43, 53: 45, 54: 46, 55: 44, 56: 91, 57: 93})
    return translated.rstrip("0")
```

And here's the script/output I used to test it:

```
import tinybf

original_code = "--<-<<+[+[<+>--->->->-<<<]>]<<--.<++++++.<<-..<<.<+.>>.>>.<<<.+++.>>.>>-.<<<+."
compressed_code = tinybf.compress(original_code)

print(compressed_code) # 7#!00"7!'!7?,,,?#B!?.>!$,.>?!.
print(len(original_code), len(compressed_code)) # 78 39

new_code = tinybf.decompress(compressed_code)
print(new_code == original_code) # True
```

Any advice on the code or improvements I could make? I'm also looking for name advice if possible - I settld on TinyBF for this question, but I also considered Braincrunch and Tinyfuck, so if you have thoughts on those, that'd be great.

Answer (score 7):

Since you seem to want code golf over readable code this may not be the answer you want. All the suggestions I make are things I would prefer, but I don't think it's that uncommon for others to disagree. The outcome either way is still pretty ugly.

- Your code isn't PEP 8 compliant, and is generally pretty hard to read.
- Your one-line docstrings are quite poor, docstring wise. Contrast with:

  > ```
  > """Compress Brainfuck code to TinyBF"""
  > ```
- Use `str.maketrans` rather than manually make the translation table.

  ```
  COMPRESS_TABLE = str.maketrans({'>': '2', '<': '3', '+': '4', '-': '5', '.': '6', ',': '7', '[': '8', ']': '9'})
  ```

  Alturnately you can define both from a common string.

  ```
  _COMPRESS_STR = '>2 <3 +4 -5 .6 ,7 [8 ]9'
  COMPRESS_TABLE = str.maketrans(dict(_COMPRESS_STR.split()))
  DECOMPRESS_TABLE = str.maketrans(dict(_COMPRESS_STR[::-1].split()))
  ```
- I would prefer `itertools.zip_longest` over manually zipping and justifying.
- You can split `decompress` over multiple lines to make the code more readable.

```
import itertools

_COMPRESS_STR = '>2 <3 +4 -5 .6 ,7 [8 ]9'
COMPRESS_TABLE = str.maketrans(dict(_COMPRESS_STR.split()))
DECOMPRESS_TABLE = str.maketrans(dict(_COMPRESS_STR[::-1].split()))


def compress(code: str) -> str:
    """Compress Brainfuck code into TinyBF"""
    return "".join(
        chr(int(a + b))
        for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(
            *2*[iter(code.translate(COMPRESS_TABLE))],
            fillvalue="0",
        )
    )


def decompress(code: str) -> str:
    """Decompress TinyBF into Brainfuck"""
    return (
        "".join(str(ord(c)) for c in code)
            .translate(DECOMPRESS_TABLE)
            .rstrip("0")
    )
```